# Implementing JSVC directly without apache-commons-daemon jar

Tags: java, jsvc, apache-commons-daemon

According to the apache commons documentation (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html), I should be able to run my application as a daemon directly using jsvc without implementing the Daemon class:

> Directly
>
> Write a Class (MyClass) that implements the following methods:
>
> - void init(String[] arguments): Here open configuration files, create a trace file, create ServerSockets, Threads
> - void start(): Start the Thread, accept incoming connections
> - void stop(): Inform the Thread to terminate the run(), close the ServerSockets
> - void destroy(): Destroy any object created in init()
>
> Store it in a jarfile and use as above:
>
> ./jsvc -cp my.jar MyClass

MyClass implements the above methods, and does not implement the Daemon class.  However if I try to invoke jsvc as above without including the commons-daemon.jar in my class path,

I get the following error:

```
Cannot find the daemon loader org/apache/commons/daemon/support/DaemonLoader
java_init failed
```

If I include it in the classpath, everything works fine., i.e.

```
./jsvc -cp commons-daemon.jar:my.jar MyClass
```

My understanding from the documentation is that I shouldn't need to include the commons-daemon.jar if I'm not using anything from that library, but just invoking jsvc directly on my class with the required methods implemented.   Is this incorrect?   I don't want to bundle any unnecessary jars with my package.

Answer (score 0):

*I should be able to run my application as a daemon directly using jsvc without implementing the Daemon class* Correct.

*However if I try to invoke jsvc as above without including the commons-daemon.jar in my class path.* Here is where you have gone wrong. You need the `commons-daemon.jar`, you just aren't implementing `Daemon`. Apache JSVC still needs it.

Comment: Is that an error in their documentation?  Cause they clearly leave out including the commons-daemon.jar in the example.

Comment: @brercia Clearly leaving it out does not work. Their documentation may assume you have set the `CLASSPATH` variable. I hesitate to say it's an error, but I suppose *omission* is fair.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I think I'll post on their mailing list to clarify what they are intending there.  I may be mistaken, but believe I have had this working in the past without ever including the jar in the cp.